# php download save file

Tags: php, download, save, export

```
$filename = "members.csv";
if($_POST['SaveFileButton'] != ""){
  header ("Content-Type: application/download");
  header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
  header ("Content-Length: " . filesize("$filename"));
  $fp = fopen("$filename", "r");
  fpassthru($fp);}
```

Sometimes this works perfectly and downloads the file.
Sometimes it displays the entire file contents at the top of the webpage, as though I had used echo, followed by the normal webpage underneath it.
I can't figure out why it's printing it to the screen.

The only unusual thing I've changed in this php file lately was adding an OnUpdate event to my Select ListBox.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function listbox_update(){
        var fullname = document.getElementById("listboxid").value;
        var editcode = document.getElementById("codeid").value;
        var filter = document.getElementById("filterid").value;
        document.location.href="/php/members.php?fullname="+fullname+"&filter="+filter+"&editcode="+editcode;}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have `exit` under it so it stops the script from continuing with normal loading?

Comment: I just tried that and it had no effect.  The file dump still fills the screen and the rest of the normal webpage doesn't appear because of the exit.  I didn't used to have this problem with the script.  The only unusual thing I added this morning was a java thing for imposing an OnChange event on a select listbox.

Comment: Run Script:  electronrock.com/php/members2.php _____ View Script: electronrock.com/php/members2.txt    _____    This should help you troubleshooters find the problem. Thanks.

Comment: What else is on the php side above the script you have already posted?

Comment: You ask "what else is on..."   you can view my entire script at _____electronrock.com/php/members2.txt ____and you can play the script at   _____electronrock.com/php/members2.php____that's where you can click DOWNLOAD and see the file dump at the top of the webpage.

Comment: You can't have any output before you do `header()`. Move that top script to the bottom, then make sure there is no space before `<?php`

Comment: I read further, you are doing heredoc, so you need to include it in that part of the code. Any output to the browser of anything, including empty space will mess up your header.

Comment: ("Move that top script to the bottom") Yes thank you that fixed it.  I have been moving that script back and forth from top to bottom lately and that's why Download was working intermittently.  I don't understand your comment regarding heredoc, you see I'm using it for a variable assignment, right?

Comment: Yeah you are using it to create your html, so you need to place that javascript part in the `heredoc` portion that will print to the page.

Comment: I think if I were you, I would build that whole page differently, it's very hard to follow. In my opinion, you need to break it up into parts, each having it's own task and then include elements that you need. You will save yourself a lot of hardship down the road that way.

Comment: ah-ha yes of course I see it now.   the java script is supposed to be included in $w because $w is the entire html webpage.   ("build that whole page differently") yes as I learn more about best-practices for php format I will clean it up.    I only used heredoc <<< in cases where the number of html lines was large enough to bother expressing it that way,   using   \"   is a nuisance

Comment: Yeah exactly. For the rebuilding, it doesn't need a total redo, it's more that you need to move your functions into pages that you include so you don't clutter up the page you are working on and also you should make some of what you have now into functions.

Comment: And instead of `heredoc` I would probably make those inclusions instead as as separate html snippit files. That way it's easier to work on each piece.